# failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs

Tags: php, linux, file, authentication, warnings

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 & xampp 5.6.30.  I am trying to create a simple login program using file with validation but I am facing problem while putting my data into a file named "login.txt".

**Error:**

```
file_put_contents(login.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP/Practice/PHP Functions/Login Validation/login.php on line 38
```

**My code:**

```
$input = $userName.'|'.$userPassword.'\n';

$myfile = file_put_contents('login.txt', $input.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: That's a permission denied error...are you saving the `login.txt` file inside of the `/opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP/Practice/PHP Functions/Login Validation/` folder?...if not, then run this command `stat theFolder` and post the output.

Answer (score 27):

This error is due to file permissions. The php/apache user does not have the permissions to write in the directory. One way of fixing that is to change the mod byte of the directory with the command `chmod`. You need super permissions to execute this modification if your session user does not own the directory.

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/directory
```

The mod `777` set read/write and execution to directory for every users on the system. The `R` option applies recursively the modification to every files and sub-directories. So, you can change the permission of all the contents of your htdocs directory all at once.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod

Comment: change permission to 777 is bad idea, because it gives permission to anybody to read and write into directory.
In Ubuntu, apache user usualy `www-data` (uid=33). Change the owner of directory to this user with: `chown -R www-data /path/to/directory`

Comment: I tried this command and its works.  $sudo chmod 0422 login.txt

Answer (score 9):

Permission errors can be solved using the following two methods.

## Method 1:

#### Find web server user

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

Note: It will be **daemon** by default if you haven't changed it.

[Web Server Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqW0Q.png)

#### In my case it's *daemon*, replace it with yours in following command.

```
sudo chown -R daemon /opt/lampp/htdocs/[Working Project]/
```

As in Linux `chown` is used to change ownership of any folder or file. So this command gives ownership of that folder to the `daemon` user, which will enable the `daemon` user to have complete access to that folder and everything inside it too.

## Method 2:

#### Give All permissions to that file.

The following command gives `Read`, `Write` and `Execute` permissions to `User`, `Group` and `Owner`. So `User` is you, who can also modify it, other programs such as text editors can also edit them, and so PHP too.

```
sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/[Working Project]/File.txt
```

Here permissions are provided using numeric number

- `7` is for all permissions `read`, `write` and `execute`.
- `6` is used for `read` and `write`.
- `5` is used for `read` and `execute`.
- `4` is used for `read` only.

The permissions are granted in ugo pattern.

- First 7 in 777 is for `User`.
- 2nd is for `Group`.
- Last is for `Others`.

##### Alternative command:

```
sudo chmod u+rwx,g+rwx,o+rwx /opt/lampp/htdocs/[Working Project]/File.txt
```

Here it is more clear that which permissions you're assigning to whom. so `u` stands for User, and is being assigned Read(r), Write(w) and Execute(e) permissions, similarly `g` is for Group, and `o` is Other.

#### Advice:

Method 2 is not suitable for most of the scenarios. I recommend using the First Method because method 2 will only give read, write and execute permissions to a file where the file must be created by you manually first. What if you wanted php to create the file according to your logic in the website. In that case this method will not work. if daemon will be the owner, it can do that only.

Answer (score 5):

You can run the command below in a terminal to give the `htdocs` folder and all of it's contents all permissions (read/write/execute for all users). Note that this is not safe in any way, especially in production!

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

Comment: please desribe it a little more

Comment: I was trying to create a dir and files through my project but it doesn't have write permission yet. So I run that command to make my htdocs to have all the permissions it needs 777 - means read/write/execute. Then it worked.

Comment: Thank you so so much dear.I was searching for this issue from 8 am and now i get the and. thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

This error is due to file permissions. The file or folder user does not have the permissions to write in the directory.

```
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /directory
```

755 – This set of permission is commonly used in web server. The owner has all the permissions to read, write and execute. Everyone else can only read and execute, but cannot make changes to the file.

https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two things. Firstly, define the full path to your login.txt file.

```
$input = $userName.'|'.$userPassword.'\n';

$loginFile = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP/Practice/PHP Functions/Login Validation/login.txt"

$myfile = file_put_contents($loginFile, $input.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Secondly, the directly you are trying to write to:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP/Practice/PHP Functions/Login Validation/
```

Is not writable. Check what user the web server is running as and give that user read/write permissions to that folder.